# Manually triggered Abide validation in Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, validation, zurb-foundation, abide

I'm trying to make myself a form, but I need to prevent some UX stuff depending on if a form was entered correctly. Is there an api for manually *issuing* the validation routine to a form's field? I know that I could listen to the post-validation events, but I actually need to start the validation from an external source.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch a change event to the form with jQuery: `$("#myForm").trigger("change");`
It will trigger validation.

Comment: It looks like Foundation is using the [jQuery Validator Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) to implement the machinary... kinda. `$("#form").valid()` doesn't do anything. Do you know if there's any way to dig into the events running around?

Comment: @AthanClark  Zurb team plans to rewrite the js side of the frameworks. It's not a good idea to rally on the js inner works at the moment.

Comment: What if you were crazy? :) Do you have an idea what nut you'd try to crack?

Comment: @AthanClark  `Foundation.libs.abide.validate : function (els, e, is_ajax)` https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js#L103

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why this isn't working / only works for the last field that needs to be validated?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted trigger on the form did not work for me. Instead using `$('#myForm').submit()` successfully triggers the checks manually. If you're using an asynchronous form you would just need to do the right `preventDefault` and `return false` on the form so that it does not submit like a normal form. I solved this by adding a universal class / data-attribute called `data-ajax-submit` or `ajax-submit` for my forms.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from Foundation 5.5.3 you can try this one:

```
$('#my_form').trigger('validate.fndtn.abide');
```